# Code after NSURLSession runs before session is over - Swift

Tags: swift, asynchronous, nsurlsession, synchronous, completionhandler

I have an app that accesses a website and downloads the HTML from that site, converts it to a string, grabs some information from the string, and then uses that for the app. My problem is that the code extracting the string runs before the data can actually be loaded. I tried putting that code in the completion handler, but that either didn't fix the problem, or I did it wrong. Here is my code:

```
for var i = 0; i <= textViewContentArray.count - 1; i++ {
    var dontCount = false
    isTaskComplete = false
    var currentWord = textViewContentArray[i]
            let url = NSURL(string: "http://words.bighugelabs.com/" + currentWord)

            var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
            let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
            let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

            let task : NSURLSessionDataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

                if error == nil {
                    //Getting String From URL Data
                    let urlContent = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

                    if urlContent.containsString("Word not found.") == false && urlContent.containsString("I couldn't find that.") == false && urlContent.containsString("Not Found") == false {
                        //Extracting Needed Info From String
                        let startPointArray = urlContent.componentsSeparatedByString("ul class=\"words\">")

                        let url1 = startPointArray[1]

                        let endPointArray = url1.componentsSeparatedByString("</ul><h3>sounds kind of like")
                        var wordsBodyString = endPointArray[0]

                        wordsBodyString = wordsBodyString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("</a></li>", withString: "")
                        let wordsBasicArray = wordsBodyString.componentsSeparatedByString("<li><a href=\"/")

                        var wordsAdvancedArray: [String] = []

                        for var i = 0; i <= wordsBasicArray.count - 1; i++ {
                            var currentWordArray = wordsBasicArray[i].componentsSeparatedByString("\">")

                            wordsAdvancedArray.append(currentWordArray[0] as! String)

                        }

                        for var i = 0; i <= wordsAdvancedArray.count - 1; i++ {
                            if count(wordsAdvancedArray[i]) < count(currentWord) {
                                shorterWordsArray.append(wordsAdvancedArray[i])
                            }
                        }

                        shorterWordsArray.removeAtIndex(0)

                        shorterWordsArrayGlobal[i] = shorterWordsArray

                        })
                        task.resume()
}
```

The urlContent constant is assigned its value before the website data is loaded. I need a way to stop that from happening. I am fairly new to programing, so keep that in mind with your answer, thank you in advance.

Comment: please show full piece of code.

Comment: I just added it in an edit. Hope that helps.

Comment: you are firing multiple URLs one after another and for every URL your completionHandler will get execute. Are you sure, this is your requirement ?

Comment: I see.  What I am trying to do is loop through all of the words in a textView and check if they have synonyms, and I am getting that information from a website. So yes I believe I need to use multiple URL Sessions.

Comment: you mean urlContent contains no value or some part of the page?